# wget --spider ram memory consumption and use of -c

Tags: wget, ram

I am using wget --spider. It is consuming a lot of ram memory. How could I limit the use of ram memory from the wget command?

`wget --spider -r -c http://www.example.org 2>&1 | grep '^--' | awk '{ print $3 }' | grep -v '\.\(css\|js\|png\|gif\|jpg\|JPG\)$' > example.txt`

"-c" does not work with --spider? I would like to put the links in example.txt and be able to continue feeding the txt with the links at another time

Comment: What is it precisely that you're trying to do? Wget doesn't really do stateful recursive downloading. -c and -r do indeed work together, just not the way you're expecting it to

Comment: @darnir Hello, I'm downloading a site that has more than 100 GB // 1 million pages. With this wget consumes practically all available ram memory (with or without --spider)

Comment: There are edge cases where recursive downloading can cause Wget's memory to shoot up massively. This is a known issue. I'd recommend you to post about this on bug-wget@gnu.org and we can help you to navigate your particular usecase